# Find memory location for current browser content

Tags: memory, html

Is there a way to find the memory location where the HTML for the currently-displayed screen may be accessed?  I would like to follow data which are being displayed and updated live, and would like to avoid the overhead of submitting repetitive get() requests to the server.  More detail: I want to monitor the HTML, probably with Perl, and construct a data stream by noting when any element's value has changed and updating the stream with the new data.  This needs to be done without human intervention -- the Perl script will simply watch and generate the output stream.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Chrome's](http://www.google.com/chrome) Inspect Element which tracks network request, including Headers for both request and response. You can also see the body of both and see cookies information...